# force sub classes to initialize a property of the super class

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, lombok, spring-mongodb

I have an abstract calss Report :

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public abstract class Report {
    private String surrogateId;
.
.
.
```

and I need to force all subclasses to fill this surrogateId property. (to have a compilation error if the subclass doesn't fill the property)

```java
@Data
@Document(collection = "active_report")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ReportActiveDevicesNotLinkedWithIO extends Report {
    private String active;
.
.
.
}
```

I've tried to use final keyword that enforce me to introduce the value of this property in the constructor,
**but** i've to generate the constructor manually instead of using Lombok, so many boilerplate code.
is there a way to acheive the same expectation without generating the construcor manually.

Comment: where will surrogateId come from?

Comment: Only provide a constructor that initializes the property.

Comment: @ChengThao surrogateId comes from a subclass, I want to provide it when I'm creating the subclass or it can be static which means for a specific subclass I know the surrogateID to pass

Comment: Where does the subclass get surrogateId?  Through it's constructor?

Comment: @ChengThao it's anothor field in the subclass that I want to make it unique between all subclasses. for example SubClass1 has a property  called installedResourceId that I want to map with the surrogateId , SubClass2 has property called installedOfferId that I want to map with surrogate in order to unify the name In the super class to perform operation on the surrogateId whatever the subclass id is

Comment: Where do SubClass1 and SubClass2 their their IDs?  Are they auto generated within the subclasses?

Answer (score 1):

Lombok does not support generation of code that takes into account properties of the supertype. That's because doing that is way more complicated than it might sound, see [this wiki post on the lombok site](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/wiki/LOMBOK-CONCEPT:-Resolution) for details on why.

Hence, what you want (I want subclasses to set this property but also maximum boilerplate busting) is not currently possible and is unlikely to be possible in the near future.

Best you can do is make the field final, use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` on the superclass, and handwrite your subclass's constructors.